# c# : how to convert binary from sql server to picture box?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, image

How to convert the binary data from sql server into a picture box? I've been searching for awhile now but nothing seems to work.

I can't post a picture but my the binary data on my sql is on @4 column and the id is @0.. I've managed to retrieve the id after login but not the picture

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you need to:

1. [Read binary data from a database](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enNL651NL651&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23%20read%20binary%20data%20from%20sql%20server)
2. Convert this binary data to an Image
3. Assign this image to a picture box

Suppose you have read the binary image from the data base into byteArray. Than you can convert this array to an Image:

```
public Image BytesToImage(byte[] byteArray)
{    
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
```

After all you can assign the result Image to PictureBox.Image property.